# Print data from a database table with laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

There was a problem when I print one record.

This is the data I want to view->

[image]

and this script on the controller ->

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
Use App\Mstcst;
use App\Mstbeasiswa;
use App\User;
Use App\Krdfas;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

class BeasiswaController extends Controller
{


   public function index(){

    $user = Auth::user()->no_anggota;
    $take = Mstcst::where('no_anggota', $user)->first();
    $CNO = $take->cno;
    echo $CNO;

    }
}
```

printed on the screen like this->

[image]

I would like printed in accordance with the existing data in the database. 0000004576 not like this 4576. Please help

Mstsct Table ->

```
CREATE TABLE DUMMY.MSTCST
(
  KDCAB      VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)          NOT NULL,
  CNO        VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)         NOT NULL,
  ALTERNATE  VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)  DEFAULT ('  ')     NOT NULL,
  DEPT       VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)          NOT NULL,
  CNM        VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)         NOT NULL,
  NAMA_ID    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)         DEFAULT 'AA'
)
```

Comment: What is the type of `CNO` column on the database? From the output that you are getting, it appears like PHP is considering the data to be numeric; it should be considered as string.

Comment: the 'cno' column data type is varchar

Comment: Try printing the `$take` variable in `tinker`. Let's see what type of data you receive.

Comment: I have yet to try, thank you advice and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the column value as string like this:

```
$CNO = sprintf('%010d', $take->cno);
echo $CNO;
```

Comment: Thanks this helps. hihihi